# Syntax for simplifying an equation in php

Tags: php

I need some help with Syntax on simplifying an equation in php (I have been using php for 3 days).  In doing some research I have found that there may possibly be an easier way to code an equation.  see existing code below:

```
<?php 
$w = $_POST['weight'];
$h = $_POST['height']; 
?>  

Hi, Your BMI is <?php echo bcmul(bcdiv($w,bcpow($h,2,2),2),703,2); ?>
```

According to a comment on http://www.php.net/manual/en I can simply the code to: bc($w/($h)^2*703).  However, I get an error message that function undefined. Is there an easier way to code this equation?

Comment: Do you ***need*** arbitrary precision math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you **need** the BC functions?  Do you **need** arbitrary precision?  If not (as most applications don't), you can just do:

```
$bmi = ($w/pow($h,2))*703;
```

And if you need to get a certain number of decimals, look into PHP's [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), for example:

```
echo 'BMI to 3 decimal places is: '.number_format($bmi,3);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.  I looks like my issue was the power function.  I am using 703 as the conversion factor lbs/sq in

Comment: 703.06957964 is the factor to convert lb/in^2 to kg/m^2